# Automatically adjusting UILabel fontsize

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have a label of `length` 100. This is the **maximum** label size i can have.

When i display a text of **10** characters it fits to it. But at times i will have to display more than `10 characters`. So is there a way to shrink the the `font` size and make it to fit in my `UILabel` of length 100 ?

```
UILabel *la = [UILabel alloc]initWithFrame(5,10,100,14)];
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just use the **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** property of UILabel [[Reference]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html).

```
la.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

From the reference:

> Normally, the label text is drawn with the font you specify in the
>   font property. 
>       If this property is set to YES, however, and the text in the text property exceeds
>       the label’s bounding rectangle, the receiver starts reducing the font size until the
>       string fits or the minimum font size is reached. This property is effective only when
>       the `numberOfLines` property is set to `1`.
>
> The default value for this property is `NO`. If you change it to `YES`, you should also set
>       an appropriate minimum font size by modifying the `minimumFontSize` property.